Playwright Test execution on Azure Windows machine fails in pipeline with error as No test found, It works perfectly with same command
I am executing test cases on microsoft azure pipeline using YAML file. When I execute the test case locally on VS code it works perfectly but when I am executing it on pipeline it shows error as No tests found. Please check below YAML file for reference. Test cases are in tests folder and directory name in playwright is
testDir: './tests',
trigger:
- none

variables:
  - group: 'Common'
  - group: 'Optimizely'

pool:
  name: VMSS-Linux-Pool

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: PlaywrightFramework
      type: git
      name: PlaywrightFramework

jobs:
- job: Build
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    displayName: 'Checkout SAGov'

  - checkout: PlaywrightFramework

      - script: |
          mv MavenSyso/* .
          rm -rf MavenSyso
          ls -l
        displayName: 'Prepare folder structure'
    
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '18.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'
    
      - script: |
          npm install
          sudo npx playwright install-deps
          npx playwright install
          npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev
        displayName: 'Install software'
    
      - script: |
          sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y jq
          buildID=$(Build.BuildId)
          jq --arg buildID "$buildID" --arg emailPass "$(EmailPassword)" '.buildID = $buildID | .executionENV = "pipeline" | .emailPassword = $emailPass' automation.config.json > temp.json && mv temp.json automation.config.json
        displayName: 'Update Automation config'
    
      - script: |
          export CI=true
          npx playwright test --project chrome
        env:
          SALESFORCE_UAT_BASEURL: $(SALESFORCE_UAT_BASEURL)
          SALESFORCE_API_USERNAME: $(SALESFORCE_API_USERNAME)
          SALESFORCE_API_PASSWORD: $(SALESFORCE_API_PASSWORD)
          SALESFORCE_API_CLIENTID: $(SALESFORCE_API_CLIENTID)
          SALESFORCE_API_CLIENTSECRET: $(SALESFORCE_API_CLIENTSECRET)
          OPTIMIZELY_USERNAME: $(Optimizely_Username)
          OPTIMIZELY_PASSWORD: $(Optimizely_Password)
        displayName: 'Run Playwright Tests'
    
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Download Allure History from Blob Storage'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'Execution'
          scriptType: 'pscore'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            az storage blob download-batch --account-name $(StorageAccountName) --source 'reports' --pattern  'Maven_Regression/AutomationReport/history/*.*' --destination '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-results'
    
      - script: |
          mv "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-results/Maven/AutomationReport/history" "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-results"
          rm -rf "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-results/MavenSyso_Regression"
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        displayName: 'Move Allure History Folder and Delete MavenSyso_Regression'
    
      - script: |
          allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report/AutomationReport
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        displayName: 'Generate Allure Report'
    
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Attach Allure Report'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-report'
          artifactName: 'Allure Report'
        
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Attach Allure Results'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-results'
          artifactName: 'allure-results'
    
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Upload Allure reports'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'Maven-NonProd'
          scriptType: 'pscore'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            az storage blob delete-batch --account-name "$(StorageAccountName)" --source 'reports' --pattern 'Maven_Regression/*'
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name $(StorageAccountName) -d reports/Maven -s "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/allure-report"


Error Logs:
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
npx playwright test --project=chrome --grep='@DBVerification'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\a_temp\705d70ac-de66-419f-9475-f2622d15d2cc.cmd""
globalVariables.startTime2024-07-24 07:53:56
Error: No tests found
Teardown finished
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Run Playwright Tests


Can you share more details about the error log and the file Structure? This will be helpful to investigate the issue further.

@KevinLu-MSFT I have attached the folder structure and logs

Thanks for your update. I have checked the folder path. Can you try to defining the workingDirectory to $(build.sourcesdirectory)/tests in the Run Playwright Tests task and run the pipeline again? you can refer to the definition in my answer

It did not worked. :(
Pipeline Update:
workingDirectory:  $(build.sourcesdirectory)/tests
Error:
##[error]Container path not found: 'C:\a\1\s\tests'

Can you share the full Azure Repo file structure? The existing screenshot is the file structure in VSCode. We need to determine the folder path based on the azure repo.

Please check attached screenshot of repo

From the screenshot, the tests folder is in the root of the azure repo, right?

Container path not found: 'C:\a\1\s\tests' This error means that the tests folder not found in the agent. By default, the pipeline will check out the repo files to the folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory) (s folder). If the tests folder is in the root path of the repo, it should be found. So please help us confirm the path of the tests folder in the repo. You can set the actual path based on the  variable: $(build.sourcesdirectory)  in the workingdir.

Thanks for direction. I printed the file structure and looks like tests folder is not getting checkout.

You can add the step: - checkout: self in yaml pipeline to checkout the current repo files. I think that it will work after checking out the tests folder.

If you need any help from my side, you may need to share full yaml pipeline definition.

I will message you privately

I know the reason now. From your YAML sample, you are using multiple repositories. In this case, you can set the workingdir with the following format:  $(build.sourcesdirectory)/reponame/tests for more detailed info, you can refer to this doc:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path


Playwright Test execution on Azure Windows machine fails in pipeline with error as No test found

Based on your description, the playwright project can work fine on your local machine. And the issue exists in Azure Pipelines.
The cause of the issue could be that the npx playwright test command is running in the folder that doesn't contain the tests.
To solve this issue, you need to confirm the test folder path in the repo.
For example:

Then you can set the workingDirectory in the Run Playwright Tests task.
For example:
- script: |
      npx playwright test --project=chrome --grep='@DBVerification'
  workingDirectory:  $(build.sourcesdirectory)/TestfolderPath
  displayName: 'Run Playwright Tests'

